# How to add sound to a shape on an animation in powerpoint using VSTO Add-in c#

Tags: c#

I want to add a sound to a shape on an animation using VSTO add-in

here is my code:

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape rectangle = curSlide.Shapes.AddShape(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRoundedRectangle, slideWidth - 110, slideHeight - 60, 100, 50);
            Sequence objSequence = curSlide.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences.Add(1);
            Effect pEffect_start = objSequence.AddEffect(rectangle, MsoAnimEffect.msoAnimEffectTransparency, MsoAnimateByLevel.msoAnimateLevelNone, MsoAnimTriggerType.msoAnimTriggerOnShapeClick, 1);
```

I can add an animation to shape, but with a sound i can not.

I do not want to add file in a location:

```
rectangle.AnimationSettings.SoundEffect.ImportFromFile(fileLocation);
```

i want to add default sounds in powerpoint:

[image]

How to do that, thank you!